# "Network Error" while importing a QML document

Tags: android, qt, import, qml, material-design

I'm trying to import [`qml-material`](https://github.com/rschiang/material) from the local directory. The standard import line `import "/path/to/the/material/folder/" as Material` doesn't work. `Material` namespace has `RaisedButton` type and when I use it like `Material.RaisedButton { ... }` it gives me error, described in the title.

**Full QML document:**

```cpp
import "/home/imran/Downloads/material-master/qml/material/" as Material

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 1080
    height: 1920
    color: "#ffffff"
    visible: true                                         

    Material.RaisedButton {
        id: materialButton
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: 'Material D'
    }
}
```

**Full log:**
`W/Qt      (20508): (null):0 ((null)): QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
 W/Qt      (20508): (null):0 ((null)): qrc:/main.qml:43 Type Material.RaisedButton unavailable
 W/Qt      (20508): /home/imran/Downloads/material-master/qml/material/RaisedButton.qml:-1 Network error
 W/Qt      (20508):`

Comment: If you want to use that style you have to include the qml file so...why not following the approach of the example project and exploit qmldir?